# Using strptime() for reading csv string into time format for R

Tags: r, csv, strptime

I have a csv file with rows filled with strings.
The string are time format which I want to read in R.

```
Tue Feb 10 12:18:39 +0000 2015
Tue Feb 10 12:19:56 +0000 2015
Tue Feb 10 12:19:57 +0000 2015
```

I know we use.

```
%a %b %d %x %z %Y
```

But how to actually write it in R?
I've Tried

```
strptime("file.csv"[ ],format="%a %b %d %x %z %Y")
```

Comment: (1) `%x` is for `"%y/%m/%d"`, you need `%X` for `"%H:%M:%S"`. (2) Have you read it into a variable first? `readLines` should suffice if it is one timestamp per line, otherwise something like `read.csv` or `read.table`. (I don't think `strptime` supports loading directly from a file.)

Answer (score 0):

Almost. You should read the csv into an object first, e.g. with `read.csv()`. Then you can

```
strptime(df$V1, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
[1] "2015-02-10 13:18:39" "2015-02-10 13:19:56" "2015-02-10 13:19:57"
```

#### Test data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Tue Feb 10 12:18:39 +0000 2015
Tue Feb 10 12:19:56 +0000 2015
Tue Feb 10 12:19:57 +0000 2015", sep = ";")  # so it will not interpret space as separator
```